# MYSQL Join all table and get the record of a field between 2 value?

Tags: mysql

I have this query,is working well,this join the few table together,this have no problem,working well

```
"SELECT post_info.post_id,username,profile_image_path,status_body,image_path,post_created_at FROM post_info 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN users_info ON post_info.user_id = users_info.user_id 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN status_of_post ON post_info.status_id = status_of_post.status_id 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN image_of_post ON post_info.image_id =image_of_post.image_id"
```

I want to get the record BETWEEN (post_id + 1) AND (post_id + 20),so I modified it to become this

```
SELECT post_info.post_id,username,profile_image_path,status_body,image_path,post_created_at FROM post_info 
LEFT OUTER JOIN users_info ON post_info.user_id = users_info.user_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN status_of_post ON post_info.status_id = status_of_post.status_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN image_of_post ON post_info.image_id =image_of_post.image_id 
WHERE post_id BETWEEN (post_id + 1) AND  (post_id + 20)
```

It state this result.

> ## 1046 - No database selected

I want to get 20 post each time the query run,based on the range of `post_id`,what is the proper way to do it??

Comment: where are you running your query?

Comment: I running at phpMyAdmin

Comment: make sure the database you want to run the query on is selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the database you are running the query for is selected in PhpMyAdmin

[image]

OR

You can change your query to include the database name like this:

```
SELECT ..... FROM DATABASE-Name.post_info
```